# Change view in wpf single page application depending upon child view model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I write an application in wpf and using mvvm pattern.
I try to implement a single page application using a ContentControl and DataTemplate.
In my application I want to switch a view depending on the child view model like this:
I have a mainwindow with a content control that its content is binding to a  property in MainViewModel:

```
public BaseViewModel CurrentViewModel { get; set; }
```

in the consturctor I wrote:

```
CurrentViewModel = new LoginViewModel();
```

in LoginViewModel I have a function that gets name and password and check if the details are correct.
if it's ok, I want to set CurrentViewModel in MainViewModel to NavigationViewModel.

but when I look for examples I find only switch the viewmodel directly in the main view model.
how can I do it???

Comment: Are you using mvvmlight?

Comment: I haven't descided yet, do you recommend me? can it help me hear?

Comment: I will post example, wait for a while.

Comment: Use two user controls.

Comment: of corse, I didn't write the full code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're asking how to change `CurrentViewModel` from within `LoginViewModel` after login completes?

You shouldn't be doing this. `LoginViewModel` should worry about logging in, and should not know anything about where it's being used, or any other part of the app.

`MainViewModel` is the one that owns the child VM and orchestrates the flow of the application, so it is `MainViewModel` that should be doing the switching.

Since you want to switch view after login completes OK, you need `LoginViewModel` to tell you that login has completed ok. The two obvious ways of doing that are:

1. `LoginViewModel` exposes a `LoginComplete` event, which `MainViewModel` subscribes to, or
2. `MainViewModel` supplies a `LoginComplete` `Action` to the `LoginViewModel` constructor, which `LoginViewModel` calls when login is complete.

.

```
public class MainViewModel 
{
    //INPC omitted for brevity
    public object CurrentViewModel { get; private set; }

    public void MainViewModel()
    {
        this.CurrentViewModel = new LoginViewModel(LoginComplete);
    }

    private void LoginComplete()
    {
        this.CurrentViewModel = new NavigationViewModel();
    }
}

public class LoginViewModel 
{
    private Action loginCompleteAction;

    public void LoginViewModel(Action loginCompleteAction)
    {
        this.loginCompleteAction = loginCompleteAction;
    }

    private void UserHasLoggedIn()
    {
        this.loginCompleteAction();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using MvvmLight framework you can build such monster.

MainWindow.xaml

> DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=Main}"

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Content="BaseView" Height="25" Width="80" Command="{Binding SwitchToBaseCommand}"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="NavigationView" Height="25" Width="100" Command="{Binding SwitchToNavigationCommand}"/>
    </Grid>
    <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}"/>
</Grid>
```

BaseView.xaml

> DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=BaseViewModel}"

```
<Grid>
    <Label Content="{Binding Message}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

NavigationView.xaml

> DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=NavigationViewModel}"

```
<Grid>
    <Label Content="{Binding Message}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

App.xaml

> xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:WpfApplication.Views" xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:WpfApplication.ViewModel"

```
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfApplication233.ViewModel" />

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:BaseViewModel}">
            <Views:BaseView/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:NavigationViewModel}">
            <Views:NavigationView/>
        </DataTemplate>

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

ViewModelLocator.cs

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the ViewModelLocator class.
    /// </summary>
    public ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<BaseViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<NavigationViewModel>();
    }

    public MainViewModel Main
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
        }
    }

    public BaseViewModel BaseViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<BaseViewModel>();
        }
    }

    public NavigationViewModel NavigationViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<NavigationViewModel>();
        }
    }

    public static void Cleanup()
    {
        // TODO Clear the ViewModels
    }
}
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ViewModelBase currentViewModel;
    public ViewModelBase CurrentViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return this.currentViewModel;
        }

        set
        {
            this.currentViewModel = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentViewModel");
        }
    }
    public RelayCommand SwitchToBaseCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(() => SwitchToBase());
        }
    }

    public RelayCommand SwitchToNavigationCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(() => SwitchToNavigation());
        }
    }

    public void SwitchToBase()
    {
        CurrentViewModel = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<BaseViewModel>();
    }

    public void SwitchToNavigation()
    {
        CurrentViewModel = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<NavigationViewModel>();
    }

}
```

BaseViewModel.cs

```
public class BaseViewModel :ViewModelBase
{
    public string Message {get; set;}
    public BaseViewModel()
    {
        Message = "Message from BaseViewModel View Model";
    }
}
```

NavigationViewModel.cs

```
    public class NavigationViewModel:ViewModelBase
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public NavigationViewModel()
    {
        Message = "Message from Navigation View Model";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is appropriate to use `DataTemplates` if you want to dynamically switch `Views` depending on the `ViewModel`:

```
<Window>
   <Window.Resources>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModelA}">
         <localControls:ViewAUserControl/>
      </DataTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModelB}">
         <localControls:ViewBUserControl/>
      </DataTemplate>
   <Window.Resources>
  <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentView}"/>
</Window>
```

If `Window.DataContext` is an instance of `ViewModelA`, then `ViewA` will be displayed and `Window.DataContext` is an instance of `ViewModelB`, then `ViewB` will be displayed.

The best example I've ever seen and read it is made by [Rachel Lim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/302677/rachel). [See the example.](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/)

Comment: of corse, I didn't write the full code, I want to know how change the current view from, for ex., ViewModelA