# How to switch windows in wpf without closing and opening a new window?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, window

I'm using C# - wpf with a design pattern of MVVM and I have a question about that, 
how do I change the view, for example, from LOGIN view to SIGNUP view without opening a new window and closing the previous one. By that, the window will not close and just will change its view?

Comment: I think you should take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19654295/10857604).

Comment: You could set login control visibility to collapsed and the signup visibility to visible and vice versa.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34307404/change-view-in-wpf-single-page-application-depending-upon-child-view-model/34308379#34308379